# Drag and Drop connected Items

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I'm making a Drag&Drop List to sort some "Module".
I want to connect an input so you can name it.

[image]

So now I want to sort this in the grey div.
But this happens:

[image]

You can only sort the module. I want to connect my modul with the input. So both are sort. And don't want to use a table. But I don't know how to do this.

```
$("#list_testdata ol").droppable({
    activeClass: "ui-state-default",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).find(".placeholder").remove();
        $("<li></li>").text(ui.draggable.text()).appendTo(this);
        $(this).append('<input type="text" value="test">');

    }
}).sortable({
    items: ":not(.placeholder)",
    sort: function() {
        $(this).removeClass("ui-state-default");
        $("ul, li").disableSelection();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it fixed by putting it together in a div.

```
$(this).append('<div class="list_testdata_div"><input type="text" value="Bezeichnung"><li>' + li_val + '</li></div>');
```